# why shasum of a file with content of 123 does not mach blob hash?

Tags: git

I make a file in git repo with contetnt of `123` and I see through objects and find a blob with hash of:

```
190a18037c64c43e6b11489df4bf0b9eb6d2c9bf
```

but when if run this command that suppose to print the hash above:

```
echo 'blob 4\0123' | shasum
```

I get this:

```
12c55a184e0ec9ac5596c256f296f09993508d17
```

whit a string like `abc` it works ok why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `\0123` isn't interpreted as `\0` followed by `123`, it's interpreted as the single character `\0123` (Octal 123, i.e. hex 0x53, i.e. the letter `S`).

Try `echo -e 'blob 4\0000123' | shasum` — it works on my system at least. The `\0` escape consumes a maximum of three more digits, so `\0000` gets you your null byte and then `123` escapes unharmed.